# The included URLconf 'appName.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Checking the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/) doesn't show any potential cause for the error. I have a django project
with a number of apps (dir layout:

[image]
)

**settings.py** (cryptoboard):

```
...
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "cryptousers.CryptoUser" 

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'leads',
    'rest_framework',
    'frontend',
    'knox',
    'cryptousers',
    'cryptocurrency',
]
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'cryptoboard.urls'
```

**urls.py** (cryptoboard):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('', include('leads.urls')),
    path('', include('cryptousers.urls')),
    path('', include('cryptocurrency.urls')) # <== WORKS IF COMMENTED OUT
]
```

**urls.py** (cryptocurrency):

```
import sys

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('get_currency_latest/', views.get_latest_currency, name='get_currency_latest'),
    # this used to work 
    # url(r'^get_currency_on_date/(?P<date_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',
    #     views.get_currency_on_date, name='get_currency_on_date'),
    # # Sample:
    # #       http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_currency_between_dates/2020-11-24/2020-11-25 
    # url(r'^get_currency_between_dates/(?P<date_start_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/(?P<date_end_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$',
    #     views.get_currency_between_dates, name='get_currency_between_dates')
    re_path(r'^get_currency_on_date/(?P<date_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',
         views.get_currency_on_date, name='get_currency_on_date'),
    re_path(r'^get_currency_between_dates/(?P<date_start_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/(?P<date_end_day>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$',
        views.get_currency_between_dates, name='get_currency_between_dates')         
]
```

The same error is thrown regardless whether the urls.py above is as it is or empty.

*views.py* (cryptocurrency)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import json

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime
from django.views import generic

from .coins_constants import coins_ids, IS_DEBUG_MODE, DATE_FORMAT
from .get_coins_scheduler import update_coins_table
from .models import Currency

from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .setup_test_db.setup_debug_tables import init_debug_tables

if IS_DEBUG_MODE:
    print('[!!!INFO!!!] DEBUG MODE SET! USING GENERATED TABLES')
    init_debug_tables()


# Don't use django for ui
def get_latest_currency(self):
    """
    Return most up to date value
    """
    update_coins_table()
    up_to_date_currency = Currency.objects.order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:len(coins_ids)]

    return JsonResponse({"up_to_date_currency": list(up_to_date_currency.values())})
```

(all views are functions at this point).

*models.py* (cryptocurrency):

```
from django.db import models

class DebugConf(models.Model):
    is_setup = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    debug_setup_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.is_setup


class Currency(models.Model):
    currency_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    currency_value = models.FloatField()
    currency_value_in_dollars = models.FloatField()
    currency_value_in_dollars_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency_name


class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transaction_amount = models.FloatField()
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    transaction_currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_buyer = models.ForeignKey('cryptousers.CryptoUser', related_name='transaction_buyer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_seller = models.ForeignKey('cryptousers.CryptoUser', related_name='transaction_seller', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.transaction_currency
```

Full stack trace:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'cryptoboard.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Most answers to similar questions suggest to look for typos in the string 'urlpatterns' but this doesn't seem to be the case here. What am I missing?

Comment: `If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.` Are you sure you included all the `import` statements in your question?

Comment: @SLDem Yes, I don't really see anything amiss.(all apps were included; the views were "manually" tested)

Comment: you are using a `re_path` but I don't see it imported anywhere, maybe thats the issue? Could also be that your `url`s are improperly written

Comment: Nope, that's not it.

Comment: I've no clue what else could it be, why are you not willing to use the previous version with just a `url`?

Comment: on the last re_path in urls.py, the "/" is missing, Should be "d{2})/$" at the end - at least that''s how they do it in the documentation - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Do the models in cryptousers rely on cryptocurrency and vice versa?

Comment: @SLDem url() was used in django <2.*

Comment: @fuser60596 tried it; still the same

Comment: @schillingt cryptocurrency relies on cryptousers

Comment: What about the remaining included url patterns? Sure they are ok?

Comment: @Razenstein Yes, removing cryptocurrency from the list of apps/urls "works"

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the relative imports.
Change `from . import views` to `from cryptocurrency import views` and try with that...

Comment: Looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220736/1079483

Comment: @JuanMi Gabarron Tried it, same. Ran manage.py with break points ...

Comment: If you change the order of the main urls.py and write as the first in the list the failing one.. is it throwing the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure why it works, but deleting all tables, recreating and rerunning migrations, and reordering the urls:

**urls.py** (cryptoboard)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('', include('leads.urls')),
    path('', include('cryptousers.urls')),
    path('', include('cryptocurrency.urls')) 
]
```

to

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('cryptocurrency.urls')), # <= DOES NOT DEPEND ON ANY OF THE APPS 
                                              # BELOW (ONLY A MODEL FROM CRYPTOUSERS)
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('', include('leads.urls')),
    path('', include('cryptousers.urls')),
]
```

works in my case.

The circular error import exception message seems to be an umbrella message in that, it cannot be caused **only** by an actual circular import. Running **manage.py** in the debugger revealed that a package (pika) was also missing (needed by dramatiq) among other stuff ...

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an import of re_path like commented already:

```
from django.urls import  re_path
```

As this will always cause an error, you must  have got a reference to a  re_path by some way . . And THAT re_path can not be used like re_path(...) because it must be a different type of object  ... now lets find the source if that re_path

Comment: This was not it; even with from django.urls import path, re_path, include # there seems to be a problem with circular imports

Comment: Another idea: the error message appears if you execute some code at startup that needs urls but urls are not yet parsed ... the only code outside functions that is immediately executed at startup is that "if IS_DEBUG_MODE ..... init_debug_tables()". Could you temporary delete that and see if that help. I have no idea what that is for but it is executed at startup in your app

Comment: The startup code doesn't need the URLs (it adds entries to a table). Even removing that step entirely, the circular import still occurs. At this point I'm not that sure if it's really a circular import error or just shoddy design and a completely different exception is thrown and caught under an umbrella circular import handler. Django's design seems rather poor IMO

Comment: I've tried changing the order in which the urls are being imported to no avail.