# Is this a circular import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

(follow up to:

[The included URLconf 'appName.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753866/the-included-urlconf-appname-urls-does-not-appear-to-have-any-patterns-in-it?noredirect=1#comment116258667_65753866)
)

My site project directory looks like:

[image]

(cryptocurrency, cryptoboard, cryptousers, frontend, leads, polls are apps).

I think that:

**setup_debug_table.py**(cryptocurrency):

```
import random
from datetime import timedelta

from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import now

from .coins_constants import NO_OF_DAYS, NO_OF_HOURS, coins_ids
from .models import Currency, Transaction, DebugConf
from cryptoboard.cryptousers.models import CryptoUser

def init_debug_tables():
    # Check if debug table has already been initialized
    debug_conf = DebugConf.objects.all()
    if debug_conf.exists():
        return

    # Clear tables
    CryptoUser.objects.all().delete()
    Currency.objects.all().delete()
    Transaction.objects.all().delete()
```

specifically, line:

```
from cryptoboard.cryptousers.models import CryptoUser
```

is what's causing the error (CryptoUser is a model in a different app (cryptousers)), somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220736/1079483) answer.

**models.py**, on the other hand, looks fine:

**models.py**(cryptocurrency)

```
from django.db import models

class DebugConf(models.Model):
    is_setup = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    debug_setup_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.is_setup


class Currency(models.Model):
    currency_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    currency_value = models.FloatField()
    currency_value_in_dollars = models.FloatField()
    currency_value_in_dollars_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency_name


class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transaction_amount = models.FloatField()
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    transaction_currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_buyer = models.ForeignKey('cryptousers.CryptoUser', related_name='transaction_buyer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_seller = models.ForeignKey('cryptousers.CryptoUser', related_name='transaction_seller', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.transaction_currency
```

Stack trace:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\dev\.virtualenvs\crypto-currency-board-2JkLYBxc\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'cryptoboard.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Is the import of a model from a different app circular?

Comment: No the import of a model of a different app is not circular, it is circular when two files are trying to import from each other, resulting in the fact that both files need each other to be loaded first which is not possible. This kind of issue can happen if both of your apps models have Foreign Keys or some other relation to each other. This can be resolved by just putting the string name of the model in the foreign key instead of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should just be:

```
from cryptousers.models import CryptoUser
```

Here is a good article explaining circular imports if you are curious:
https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Importing models from another app is fine so long as the models don't define themselves through each other.